# Cannot save tar.gz file to usr/local

Tags: 10.10, installation, hadoop

I'm using the following instruction to install and configure Hadoop on Ubuntu 10.10.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#installation

I tried to save the compressed tar.gz file to `/usr/local/` but it just won't save.

I've tried saving the tar.gz in my home folder and desktop and copying the files to the desired folder, but I get an error that tells me I don't have permission.

How do I save and extract a tar.gz folder to `/usr/local/hadoop`?

Comment: The instructions there say you should be using `sudo` to execute commands. If you're following those directions to the letter the problem might be that you don't have sudo privileges. Is this a machine that someone else is the primary administrator of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be root to write to `/usr/local`. Run the file manager as root using

```
gksu nautilus
```

Then copy and paste or extract the archive.